# Apps Logs at NewRelic

Tags: logging, newrelic

Sorry for maybe silly question but I haven't found answer neither on the web or New Relic features list.

**Has New Relic ability to see apps logs?**

If so please provide detailed steps in UI to find this tab/option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently New Relic does not have a away to monitor application or server logs. However this question is a good one to bring up in the New Relic Community Forums http://discuss.newrelic.com, there may be more customers interested in this and it would be a good change to get it on the radar for a possible New Relic feature.